# SQL to return rows where one column is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a site that posts articles, and certain articles are assigned a location and a profile so only people in that location and relevant profile can see it.

I have a query which returns the location and the count of articles assigned to that location

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.location, COUNT( DISTINCT article.id) AS Number 
FROM ar.locations 
JOIN ar.articleLocation 
     ON articleLocation.locationId = locations.id 
JOIN ar.article 
     ON article.id=articleLocation.articleId 
JOIN ar.articleProfile 
     ON article.id = articleProfile.articleId 
WHERE article.createDate >= '2013-11-30' 
AND article.startDate <= '2014-05-30' 
AND articleProfile.profileId 
     IN ('1000000410','1000000408','1000000393') 
AND articleLocation.locationId IN ('250','194','195','204','281') 
GROUP BY locations.id, locations.location 
ORDER BY locations.location
```

This returns the results

```
id  location    Number
194 LocationA     1
250 LocationB    16
281 LocationC     2
```

But in the query there are 2 other location Ids, and because there are no articles assigned to those locations, nothing is being returned for those IDS

Ideally I would like

```
    id  location    Number
    194 LocationA     1
    250 LocationB    16
    281 LocationC     2
    204 LocationD     0
    195 LocationE     0
```

I can't seem to figure out how to bring back 0 if no articles exist in that location.
Any help/pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Also I'm more than open to suggestions if there is a more efficient/better way of doing what I'm currently doing.

Comment: You can use a LEFT JOIN. Please see my `final answer` below :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `LEFT JOIN` for this purpose, as below. The parentheses were not located properly, which have been corrected below.

```
SELECT locations.id, locations.location, COALESCE(COUNT( DISTINCT article.id), 0) AS Number 
FROM ar.locations 
JOIN ar.articleLocation 
     ON articleLocation.locationId = locations.id 
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT article.* FROM ar.article 
JOIN ar.articleProfile 
     ON article.id = articleProfile.articleId 
WHERE article.createDate >= '2013-11-30' 
AND article.startDate <= '2014-05-30' 
AND articleProfile.profileId 
     IN ('1000000410','1000000408','1000000393') 
) article
ON article.id=articleLocation.articleId 
WHERE articleLocation.locationId IN ('250','194','195','204','281') 
GROUP BY locations.id, locations.location 
ORDER BY locations.location;
```

The COALESCE function will print 0 if there are no records (instead of returning NULL).

**References**:

[Using Outer Joins on TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

[COALESCE (Transact-SQL) on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. The issue I'm having however is the query doesn't return any information for those 2 IDS at all. 
If it was returning LocationD: NULL, I would be happy, but the problem is its not returning LocationD or locationE in the query what so ever. I've copied your query and its giving me the same results at the moment.

Comment: @Shamrockonov Thank you for testing. I had placed the parentheses incorrectly. First you have to (INNER) join ar.article and ar.articleProfile. Then, you have to LEFT OUTER JOIN with ar.articleLocation. The modified query above does that.

Comment: I can't thankyou enough for the help you've given already. But query is taking issue with the "AND articleProfile.profileId IN  ('1000000410','1000000408','1000000393'), giving the error
"The multi-part identifier "articleProfile.profileId" could not be bound." Any thoughts?

Comment: Since you want to limit by articleProfile.profileId, it should also be within the sub-query. Let me change the query.

Comment: @Shamrockonov As you can see, now, the filter conditions on the article and the articleProfile tables have been inside the sub-query.

Answer (score 1):

Use Left Join on Article table. 
That will add NULL into rows where you expect to see 0. And to see 0, just you ISNULL(0,)

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to move the conditions on all tables except the `locations` table into the `on` clauses.  These are turning your outer join into an inner join:

```
SELECT l.id, l.location, COUNT( DISTINCT a.id) AS Number 
FROM ar.locations l LEFT JOIN
     ar.articleLocation al
     ON al.locationId = l.id LEFT JOIN
     ar.article a
     ON a.id = al.articleId AND
        a.createDate >= '2013-11-30' AND
        a.startDate <= '2014-05-30' LEFT JOIN
     ar.articleProfile ap
     ON a.id = ap.articleId AND
        ap.profileId IN ('1000000410', '1000000408', '1000000393') 
WHERE l.locationId IN ('250', '194', '195', '204', '281') 
GROUP BY l.id, l.location 
ORDER BY l.location;
```

Some notes:

- The `where` clause does include filtering on the first table.  Moving this to the `on` clause would not do the right thing.
- The `where` clause uses `location` rather than `articlelocation`.
- I introduced table aliases to make the query more readable.
- All the other comparison clauses are in the `on` clauses.
- I suspect that `count(a.id)` would do the same thing as `count(distinct a.id)`.